# How to automate creating GCP between two images

Tags: python, georeferencing, ground-control

How can I align Ortho1 to Ortho2.

Ortho2 is is the correct spot. Ortho1 needs to be shifted to align with Ortho2.

I know how to do this manually, with QGIS or ArcGIS create the tie points. But we have thousands of of orthos like this.

I tried to use the Auto-Georeference in ArcGIS Pro but it does not work very well.

I have the coordinates for the CP in ortho2, but I need to some how find this point in ortho1 and get the coordinates, then I would have the points table with the deltas and then can easily align them.

How can I grab the Coordinates from ortho1 that match the CP in ortho2.

Usually these CP are where 2 joints of concrete meet for form a distinct ("CP"). We have no official CP in the field.

I tried to run different algorithms on the photo like ExtractEdges, EnhanceContrast to make a more distinct feature. But still can't figure it out.

Anyone have any ideas out there. I have experience in GDAL, ArcGIS, QGIS, OTB.

I have attached the TIFF for an example if anyone what's to try.

You can download the TIFFs here
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1yLiK6NexXfrecgiAPTVNKUB_iaz2GY8m?usp=sharing

[image]